# How do I import XML file names along with the data using VBA in Excel?

Tags: xml, excel, vba, import, filenames

I have been working on a VBA macro script to help import and organize XML files regarding user requests. However, right now I'm trying to add the filename as it contains the name of the user who sent in that specific XML file. I managed to formulate a code to import the XML and add the filename at the end of each XML import but now I want to import the filename along with the data (as in on every row at the end column). As shown with XXX denoting XML data:

```
XXX1    XXX1  filename1  
XXX1    XXX1  filename1  
XXX1    XXX1  filename1  
XXX2    XXX2  filename2  
XXX2    XXX2  filename2  
XXX2    XXX2  filename2
```

Right now my code looks like this

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughFiles()

    Dim strFile As String, strPath As String, Num As Long, LR As Integer

    strPath = "C:\Requests\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xml")
    Num = 0

    While strFile <> ""

        ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("resources_Map").Import Url:= _
        (strPath & strFile)

        strFile = Dir

        Num = Num + 1

        LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LR = LR + 1
        Cells(LR, "A") = strFile

    Wend

MsgBox "This code ran successfully for " & Num & " XML file(s)", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Current code works like this:

```
XXX1 XXX1  
filename1  
XXX2  XXX2  
filename2
```

It looks like a simple adding a column but I'm not sure how to add values to all the rows in the XML import. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Range** method to update filenames. variables `lngStart` and `lngEnd` will have start and end row numbers.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim strFile As String, strPath As String, Num As Long, LR As Integer
    Dim lngStart, lngEnd As Long

    strPath = "C:\Requests\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xml")
    Num = 0

    lngStart = 2 'considering row 1 has headers. if not change it to 1.
    While strFile <> ""

        ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("resources_Map").Import URL:= _
        (strPath & strFile)

        strFile = Dir

        Num = Num + 1

        lngEnd = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).Value = strFile

        lngStart = lngEnd + 1

    Wend

MsgBox "This code ran successfully for " & Num & " XML file(s)", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Nagarajan! It worked pretty well but "strFile=Dir" needed to be underneath the range code in order for the filenames to display in the correct order (if not it will be skewed by one file). While this works for a batch import, I intend to add future xml data into this worksheet and this method will replace all the previously imported filenames, is there a way to modify this code to retain values from past imports?

Comment: Update: Instead of lngStart=2, I put lngStart=LastRow + 1 where LastRow is a method to find the last row in the worksheet. This makes the data to only import from the last row onwards. This is my first time using stackoverflow do I need to put this update in the question? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function to retrieve the file names and add in:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub AddFileNames()
    Dim destinationCell As Range, results() As String
    Set destinationCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")  '<==Set to first cell where you want to add the names from
    results = GetXMLFileNames("C:\Requests\*.xml")
    If results(UBound(results)) <> vbNullString Then
        destinationCell.Resize(UBound(results) + 1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(results)
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GetXMLFileNames(ByVal folderPath As String) As Variant
    Dim f As String, names() As String, counter As Long
    ReDim names(0 To 1000)
    f = Dir(folderPath)
    Do Until f = vbNullString
        names(counter) = f
        f = Dir
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop
    ReDim Preserve names(0 To counter - 1)
    GetXMLFileNames = names
End Function
```

Comment: Did you try this?